# counting program break when cycles complete

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have dictionary called `nested_group_map` based on 4 groups each with a key called `shed_count` in each group. How could I make a program that will add `+1` to each `shed_count` in a range loop fashion by iterating through the `nested_group_map` keys/values and then break when the number of `cycles` through the range loop is complete? Basically what I am thinking is the `shed_count` in each group should == `cycles` which 12.

Sorry sort of an odd question, hopefully this makes sense.

```
import numpy as np

cycles = 12

nested_group_map = {
    'group_l1n' : {
    'shed_count': 0,
    },
    'group_l1s' : {
    'shed_count': 0,
    },
    'group_l2n' : {
    'shed_count': 0,
    },
    'group_l2s' : {
    'shed_count': 0,
    }
}


def cycle_checker(cycles):
    check_sum = [int(cycles)]
    print(f'cycle_checker after for loop sum is {sum(check_sum)}')
    print(f'cycle_checker appended after for loop is {check_sum}')

    for group in nested_group_map:
        for k,v in nested_group_map[group].items():
            if k in ('shed_count'):
                check_sum.append(int(v))
                
    print(f'cycle_checker after for loop sum is {sum(check_sum)}')
    print(f'cycle_checker appended after for loop is {check_sum}')

    return np.all(check_sum)


while not cycle_checker(cycles):
    for group in nested_group_map:
        for v in nested_group_map[group].values():
            v = v + 1
            print(v)
```

This just creates an infinite loop, any newbie tips appreciated : )

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem at all. What is the logical/mathematical rule that tells you how many `cycles` there should be? What is a "cycle" for you, and why is `shed_count` called that? What are the values in the `check_sum` list supposed to represent, and what is the logical/mathematical rule that you want to apply to that list? And why are you using `np.all` on a plain Python list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
for v in nested_group_map[group].values():
    v = v + 1
```

you aren't changing `nested_group_map` in any way. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61173390/9997212) for a brief explanation. For this, you have to explicity write to it using a key:

```
group_map = nested_group_map[group]
for k, v in group_map.items():
    group_map[k] = v + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete answer with the help of @enzo. I also had to remove the `np.all()` for what ever reason I couldnt get that too work. So I used `return sum(check_sum) == len(check_sum) * cycles` instead in the `cycle_checker` function that returns boolean

```
cycles = 12

# data structure
nested_group_map = {
    'group_l1n' : {
    'shed_count': 0,
    },
    'group_l1s' : {
    'shed_count': 0,
    },
    'group_l2n' : {
    'shed_count': 0,
    },
    'group_l2s' : {
    'shed_count': 0,
    }
}


def cycle_checker(cycles):
    check_sum = [int(cycles)]
    #print(f'cycle_checker after for loop sum is {sum(check_sum)}')
    #print(f'cycle_checker appended after for loop is {check_sum}')

    for group in nested_group_map:
        for k,v in nested_group_map[group].items():
            if k in ('shed_count'):
                check_sum.append(int(v))
        
    #print(f'cycle_checker after for loop sum is {sum(check_sum)}')
    print(f'cycle_checker appended after for loop is {check_sum}')
    
    # returns boolean
    return sum(check_sum) == len(check_sum) * cycles


def run_another_cylce():
    for group in nested_group_map:
        group_map = nested_group_map[group]
        for k, v in group_map.items():
            group_map[k] = v + 1
            
            
while not cycle_checker(cycles):
    run_another_cylce()
```

This is what I was hoping to see, basically fill the bins (`shed_count`) until they are ALL filled up to `cycles`

This prints:

```
cycle_checker appended after for loop is [12, 0, 0, 0, 0]
cycle_checker appended after for loop is [12, 1, 1, 1, 1]
cycle_checker appended after for loop is [12, 2, 2, 2, 2]
cycle_checker appended after for loop is [12, 3, 3, 3, 3]
cycle_checker appended after for loop is [12, 4, 4, 4, 4]
cycle_checker appended after for loop is [12, 5, 5, 5, 5]
cycle_checker appended after for loop is [12, 6, 6, 6, 6]
cycle_checker appended after for loop is [12, 7, 7, 7, 7]
cycle_checker appended after for loop is [12, 8, 8, 8, 8]
cycle_checker appended after for loop is [12, 9, 9, 9, 9]
cycle_checker appended after for loop is [12, 10, 10, 10, 10]
cycle_checker appended after for loop is [12, 11, 11, 11, 11]
cycle_checker appended after for loop is [12, 12, 12, 12, 12]
```